# HTML JS - Disable clicking possibility through the CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

,hello Gentlemann please

**1°** How can i disable the click Behavior onclick through the css class please?

**2°** I can't use ID in the HTML Element because i'm not able to insert any ID in the code, so i need to use the Class the make the magic happen.

**3°** In all my Tries, none of them still works.

**Element and CSS Class that i need to disable if clicked:**

```
<label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers">
 <span class="p5_effect_tooltip_b top">
     <span class="numero">999999<br><small>pending<br>payment</small></span>
     <span class="p5_custom_tooltip_b">Pre-Reserved: Jim</span>
 </span>
</label>
```

Class:    `label.inner.all.disabled.reserved.my_numbers`

1° First Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inner.all.disabled.reserved").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

2° Second Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".label.inner.all.disabled.reserved").click(function() {
        $("label").off("click");
    });
});
```

3° Third Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inner.all.disabled.reserved").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

4° Try:

```
$('#inner.all.disabled.reserved.my_numbers').disabled = true
```

Comment: To disable clicks using only CSS, try `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: `inner.all.disabled.reserved` - this is class, but you specify as id

Comment: Have a look at any error messages coming up on your browsers dev tools console.

Comment: @ozgur, Thanks for the Help.....But i must disable the Click behavior and maintain the Hover behavior. On mouse Hover on the element, the Tooltip must continue working. With this pointer-events attribute, all the Hover event will be disable.

Comment: @PaulodoPorto I'm sorry I didn't notice the hover neccessity

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, Thanks for the Help. I have tried this way, but the magic is not there:
`$('.inner.all.disabled.reserved.my_numbers').disabled = true` and 
`$('.inner.all.disabled.reserved.my_numbers').attr("disabled", true)`

Comment: tell me what result do you want to get? Need to disable the ability to interact with an element when a click occurs?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, Yes.......That's it!! The code between `<span></span>` are clickable...and only the classe `label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers` has one sub span tag with the class `<span class="numero">`, and the status of this Tag is **Payment Pending**...So, i can't let this Tag clickable ...understand : ) ?

Comment: I gave the answer. Is it so necessary? If not, make your comments, and I will correct the answer.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, Thanks for the Help. Yes, i must disable the Click behavior and maintain the **Hover behavior**. On mouse Hover on the element, the Tooltip must continue working. With this **pointer-events attribute**, all the Hover event will be disable. So i can't use this attribute. It does not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it best to use the Event. You can use `.preventDefault()` to stop the event action.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  function preventClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.nodeName + " Click Prevented");
    return false;
  }
  $("label.inner.all.disabled.reserved").click(preventClick).children().click(preventClick);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers">
 <span class="p5_effect_tooltip_b top">
     <span class="numero">999999<br><small>pending<br>payment</small></span>
     <span class="p5_custom_tooltip_b">Pre-Reserved: Jim</span>
 </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I specially registered the `console.log()` so that you could see that the click can be done only once.

Was it necessary?

```js
$(".inner.all.disabled.reserved").click(function(){
  console.log('This message will not show!');
}).off('click');
```

```css
.inner.all.disabled.reserved:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers">
 <span class="p5_effect_tooltip_b top">
     <span class="numero">999999<br><small>pending<br>payment</small></span>
     <span class="p5_custom_tooltip_b">Pre-Reserved: Jim</span>
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: i tested the code above and as you said, It is possible to click on the Element one time. After that, the element it is not more clickable and the Tooltip disappear completely. I can't have the possibility to click on the element even one time understand? The element must be unclickable, but preserving the Hover effect. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @PaulodoPorto, i updated the answer. Now the hover is working, but the click event is not working. Check pls.

Comment: ...and i intentionally put `console.log('This message will not show!')` in order to make sure that the element is not clickable.

Comment: i can say that, the magic still not happened. Now i have green fonts when i click on the elements, but the elements are still **clickable**  `:   )`

Comment: I specially created a rule for you with a hover so that you can see the activity of the hover. This is a test hover. But the elements cannot be clickable since I disabled the click. Check out my `jquery` code. If the elements were clickable, you would receive a console message - `console.log('This message will not show!')`.

Comment: All right, so let me show you something new.
**This is Class Status Pending.**  
`<label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers">`

When I click on the element, the class changes to this: 
`<label class="inner all disabled reserved my_numbers checked">`
This means that, the element is still clickable `:  )`, but i think, you´re on the correct way! Thank you!